# Seperate Signal Planes in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am trying to make separate signal planes in eagle using the polygon tool. The problem is that when I draw the first polygon, regardless of whether I draw it small or large once I name it to GND and hit the "Ratsnest" tool, it will just occupy the whole space of the PCB leaving no space for other planes. How can I fix that?

Also I need one of the planes to be exposed copper, by drawing a polygon on either the bstop or tstop layers, I am getting what I need. The problem is that I don't know how to connect it to another part (say a transistor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each one a seperate rank (found in the properties dialogue). The lower the number the higher the priority. So a polygon of rank 1 will be drawn first, then ones with a rank of 2 will be drawn next (being cut away by the higher priority polygon outlines).

This will allow you to have polygons inside polygons.

---

The second part of your question, if you name the polygon with the same name as the net you want it to connect to, then you can just route a trace staring from anywhere within the polygon and Eagle will know they are meant to be connected.